# How to show actual point on Bokeh plot line

Tags: bokeh

I am making a line graph using a Bokeh plot, and I want to have the actual points marked (with the line going through them) rather than just the line by itself. How can I do this? I went through the documentation and the user guide but can't seem to find the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `bokeh.plotting` you only need to call the glyph methods you want, in the order you want them rendered:

```
p = figure()
p.line(x, y)
p.circle(x, y)
```